# Rails Devise User help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In devise how would I, I am not sure how to phrase it, return a user. 
I am able to user_signed_in? but what about user.
I want to check in show if @user is the same one as the user that is currently signed in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Devise has methods like `current_user` which returns the "user" that is logged in.

Also, depending on your "User" model the helper methods will be adjust accordingly. So if you have an `Admin` class that is your devise model, you can use something like `current_admin`, and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Devise has a `current_user` helper that's available.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user == current_user
    # something
  end
end
```

But maybe you just want to do this?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks good, but kwon's solution was what I was looking for right now